# Showing progress bar while loading fragments in fragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar, progressdialog

onClick of List I'm loading Fragments in Fragment Activity. There I have used view pager. I'm loading all the viewpager at the same time using viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(Size). Until all these fragments loads to Fragment Activity. I need to display progress bar. What way i can achieve this?

Comment: Android has a widget called [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) that you can update as the data loads. I'd start by looking into that, trying something out, and maybe come back here if something doesn't work.

Comment: I was trying to add requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); to my Fragment activity to show Indeterminate ProgressBar. But obviously it didn't work. And I added same code in Fragment like getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); but the problem here is i already gave setContentView in FragmentActivity. So it's throwing error requestFeature() method should be called before adding content.

Comment: In that case you should edit your question with all the relevant code and logcat of the error output.